# Can we write a unit test for styles using enzyme, jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Can we write a unit test for styles using enzyme, jest? for example visibility item

```
display: none;

wrapper.get(0).style - do not work for me
```

Comment: It depends. How are you managing styles in your application?

Answer (score 0):

```
const display = wrapper.prop('style').display
```

Make sure wrapper is referencing the correct node.